# SQL Multi Subnet Always on High Availability

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I am configuring a SQL Always on High Availability solution using SQL Availability groups, this will be spanning two subnets.

Using Windows 2019 and SQL 2019 one node in AWS and one on Premise.

When I start the create cluster wizard I am able to add both nodes into the cluster but when I get to the next section 'Access Point for Administering the Cluster'  I only see a single network where I expected to see two, one for each subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have now resolved this issue, was caused by the AWS DNS suffixes it appends to the domains. This caused issues with our domain names.

Have changed this setting to append primary and connect specific DNS suffixes and I was able to see both networks when building the cluster.